# Is it good to use Auto-pairs plugin in Vim?

Tags: plugin-auto-pairs

I am learning Vim, and I find it useful the auto-pairs plugin generates closed paranthesis automatically.

It has some issues where I want to type a closed paranthesis but it jumps to the next closed paranthesis.

So I wanna ask if it's better to use plugin like that or learn to type the closed paranthesis myself through muscle memory?

Comment: It's totally your own decision whether you actually want to use a auto-close plugin. But if you're experiencing problems with using the plugin, you should use their issue tracker, i.e. github or gitlab etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you are a programmer and a vim beginner:

- As a beginner, you need really really a lot of time to familiar with vim built in stuff.
- There are also some plugins you can't live without them, you need time to choose and familar with them:

  - plugin manage plugin
  - resouce navigate plugin
  - code navigate plugin.
  - auto complete plugin
  - snippet plugin
  - syntax check plugin
  - status line plugin
  - color scheme plugin

The list might goes on and on, it depends on your coding language, but 
 most of time auto-pair is not one of them.

It's pretty easy to get overwhelmed. You also need extra plugin to make auto-pairs work with . repeat, so IMHO don't use it for the 1st and 2nd month, a few more key strokes wouldn't kill you.

Feel free to try it later.